# If 2 cells blank then third cell blank, if 2 cells yes then "yes" otherwise "no"

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have two cells, `A1` and `B1`.

> If `A1` and `B1` are equal to `Yes` then `C1` is `Yes` otherwise `No`
>
> If `A1` and `B1` are blank then `C1`is blank

What formula do I place in `C1` to complete this?

Comment: Untested `=if(and(a1,b1)="yes",c1="yes",if(and(a1,b1)="",c1="","no")`

Comment: @findwindow you may add the note that this is an array formula...

Comment: ? It's not an array formula.

Comment: you may want to use `and(A1:B1="Yes")`... however i was wrong... `and(a1,b1)="yes"` will just output an error...

Comment: lol I see what you mean now XD Edit: OP, yea remove the `c1` in my formula. Edit2: oh. Will test when my macro finishes XD

Comment: you may delete it and write a new comment... the more i look at it the more it looks messed up with half-vba-coding :D

Comment: Yea that's my fault. Edit: `=IF(AND(A1="yes",B1="yes"),"yes",IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),"","no"))`

Comment: are you sure? 2 times `AND(A1="yes",B1="yes")` :P

Comment: Yea, my problem is it doesn't do "no" ;_;  Edit: Which may be the 2 times you refer to lol XD Edit2: got trigger happy XD edited above^^;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(A1&B1="","",IF((A1="Yes")*(B1="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

just a hint: if there is something like `AND(A1="",B1="",.....)` (all cells need to be empty) you also can write `A1&B1&......=""`

Comment: (A1="Yes") equals true or false and true = 1 while false = 0 so having `bool*bool = and`... but you are right... i missed a `"`

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 : `=(IF(AND (A1 = "YES",B1 = "YES"), "YES", "NO"))`

Part 2 : `=(IF(AND (A1 = "",B1 = ""), "", "SOMETHING"))`